# Usar evento scroll em um elemento especifico

Tags: javascript, html

**Fala Pessoal!**

**Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar algo como no código abaixo:**

```js
const elemento = elemento.document.querySelector(".elemento")

elemento.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  // funçao aqui
})
```

**Ou isto é possível apenas com *window*?** 
Porque isto não funcionou. Alguma ideia do quê pode estar errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas vc consegue sim detectar o evento `scroll` de um elemento.

No exemplo tenho um `div` com `overflow:auto`, no `scroll` executa uma função...

```js
let elemento = document.querySelector(".elemento")

elemento.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  document.body.style.background = 'red'
  console.log('scroll na div');
})
```

```css
.elemento {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At iusto asperiores dolore, totam ex alias pariatur rerum? Sequi iure laudantium quaerat, quibusdam necessitatibus saepe nesciunt accusamus autem architecto asperiores, nobis id officiis atque, error aliquid reprehenderit cupiditate porro at ipsum dignissimos voluptate tempora. Quia ea, nesciunt modi suscipit fuga adipisci ipsa quos qui amet eligendi atque ad libero? Nobis odit laudantium, itaque eum ratione labore eaque repellendus libero ipsam rerum, perspiciatis soluta perferendis officia accusantium mollitia nihil assumenda doloribus cumque, similique quisquam doloremque commodi nemo vel? Deserunt nostrum alias incidunt consequuntur laudantium velit qui expedita, dignissimos possimus modi error corporis.</div>
```